# How to programmatically alter the visual state of a wxToggleButton?

Tags: wxpython

How to programmatically alter the visual state of a [wxToggleButton](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.ToggleButton.html#wx.ToggleButton.SetValue)? (wxPython wx-3.0-gtk2, Ubuntu 16.04)

I have three wxTopggleButtons and I want the other two to be depressed when any one button is pressed. At the moment I am doing this in the bound function to each other button:

```
self.button.SetValue(False)                   
self.button.Refresh()                         
self.button.ToggleWindowStyle()
```

It doesn't throw any errors but it doesn't make any difference to the visual appearance of the button.

Answer (score 0):

The `SetValue` should be all that is needed, with `SetValue(True)` putting it into the toggled state.

Comment: As I say, it doesn't make any difference to the visual appearance of the button.

Comment: Please provide a small runnable sample that demonstrates the problem.